# Appending the message in MD5

Tags: md5

I am trying to understand how the MD5 hashing algorithm work and have been reading the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) about it.

After one appends the message so that the length of the message (in bits) is congruent to 448 mod 512, one is supposed to

```
append length mod (2 pow 64) to message
```

From what I can understand this means to append the message with 64 bits representing the length of the message. I am a bit confused about how this is done.

1. My first questions is: is this the length of the original unappended message or the length that one gets after having appended it with the 1 followed by zeros?
2. My second question is: Is the length the length in bytes? That is, if my message is one byte, would I append the message with 63 0's and then a 1. Or if the message is 10 bytes, then I would append the message with 60 0's and 1010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The length of the unpadded message. From the [MD5 RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt), 3.2:

   > A 64-bit representation of b (the length of the message before the
   >   padding bits were added) is appended to the result of the previous
   >   step. In the unlikely event that b is greater than 2^64, then only
   >   the low-order 64 bits of b are used. (These bits are appended as two
   >   32-bit words and appended low-order word first in accordance with the
   >   previous conventions.)
2. The length is in bits. See MD5 RFC, 3.1:

   > The message is "padded" (extended) so that its length (in bits) is
   >   congruent to 448, modulo 512. That is, the message is extended so
   >   that it is just 64 bits shy of being a multiple of 512 bits long.
   >   Padding is always performed, even if the length of the message is
   >   already congruent to 448, modulo 512.

The MD5 spec is far more precise than the Wikipedia article. I always suggest reading the spec over the Wiki page if you want implementation-level detail.

> if my message is one byte, would I append the message with 63 0's and then a 1. Or if the message is 10 bytes, then I would append the message with 60 0's and 1010.

Not quite. Don't forget the obligatory bit value "1" that is always appended at the start of the padding. From the spec:

> Padding is performed as follows: a single "1" bit is appended to the
>      message, and then "0" bits are appended so that the length in bits of
>      the padded message becomes congruent to 448, modulo 512. In all, at
>      least one bit and at most 512 bits are appended.

This [reference C implementation](https://github.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms/blob/master/md5.c#L149) (disclaimer: my own) of MD5 may be of help, it's written so that hopefully it's easy to follow.

Comment: Ok, so what if the original message is one bit? After one has appended the bit 1 followed by zeros to reach a length of 448 mod 512, then what is the 64 bit representation of 8 bit length that comes after this? (if that makes any sense).

Comment: If the original message is one bit long, then the 64-bit representation of the length would be 1. If it were one byte, then it would be the 64-bit representation of 8. As for the encoding of the 64-bit integer, it will be little endian (with the lower memory address containing the lease significant part of the value).

Comment: And if 1 byte (8 bits), then the 64 bit representation would be 1000? (so 60 0's follows by 1000)

Comment: If you're referring to the integer representation (and not the memory representation), that sounds right.